# Compile angularjs templates with data to html

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I am writing an Add-In for outlook client.

Think of like the user selects a item from a drop down menu and selects insert in email while composing.

The Add-In is written using angularjs and I get json data from server side. I want to compile the json data against some angular template and get the HTML div object so I can insert it in the email body.

What are my options here and how to do it,
I have the template and json data in hand on client side when the user chooses to insert in email body. How can I compile to HTML on client side? Any pointers or examples will be appreciated.

Example:
Suppose the user selects Student2 and chooses to insert in the email
And the json data I get from the server is

```
{ "name":"John", "age":20, "city":"New York", "profilepic":"https://profilepicurl" }
```

And my template is

```
<div>
  <span><b>{{name}}</b><i>{{age}}</i></span>
  <span>{{city}}</span>
</div>
```

I want to get the below HTML so I can insert in the email

```
<div>
  <span><b>John</b><i>21</i></span>
  <span>New York</span>
</div>
```

Comment: It's not really clear what you are asking here, but *I think* you are asking how to generate static HTML from template files.  Unfortunately, Angular uses two way binding, and never generates static HTML (that is, it never replaces the Angular bindings with static values).  If what you are asking for is static content, Angular isn't the right framework.

Comment: My Add-In or extension is written using angularjs and is a website iframed inside microsoft outlook email client. There are APIs to insert HTML inside the email body. And we have a service which returns JSON payload. Since our Add-In or website is written in angularjs I want to write my templates in angularjs as well. Is there any other framework I can use to generate HTML from a template and data to fill the template.

Comment: Angular doesn't "generate HTML from a template", Angular manages the DOM to dynamically re-render HTML content based on JavaScript functions.  It **is not** a template engine, and it shouldn't be compared to them.  There are plenty of template engines about, but making recommendations for one isn't the goal of StackOverflow, and doesn't make a good question, unfortunately.

Answer (score 0):

Html:

```
<div>
  <span><b>{{myJson.name}}</b><i>{{myJson.age}}</i></span>
  <span>{{myJson.city}}</span>
</div>
```

In your angularjs Controller:

```
$scope.myJson = { "name":"John", "age":20, "city":"New York", "profilepic":"https://profilepicurl" }
```